# dynamically print the table rows

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, datatable

I've to design a **table** in a web page (jsp, jquery) in which 
the **rows should be displayed at any number according to the user choice** i.e.
if the user wants to display only 10 rows, the page should be able to display only 
10 rows and if the user wants to display only 15 rows the page should display 15 rows.
how can I do it?

Comment: feature is called pagination, google for jQuery paginator you will find plenty, simplest one that I have come across is called jQuery tablesorter plugin for static table, it cannot be easier than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many javascript library available for it, See [datatables](http://datatables.net/) (javascript library)

Check for [display tag library](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/) (server side library)

> The display tag library is an open source suite of custom tags that provide high-level web presentation patterns which will work in an MVC model. The library provides a significant amount of functionality while still being easy to use.

Comment: @BalusC, yes I know, these two are different statements

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll try it. how about using "data table" jquery plugin. Can I use it to display data from oracle data base.